# Exporting file with layers from Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, export, mapping, forest-ecology

I am brand new to using Google Earth Engine or coding in general. I have created a map in Google Earth Engine using Hansen Global Forest Change (tree cover and forest loss layers), Global Multi-resolution Terrain Elevation Data 2010 (DEM), and Landsat 8 (NDVI, I don't need so I have slashed code out). I am trying to export the layers so I can overlay them onto another map I have and print them onto a field map. My only issue is that when I export the map, it only exports the DEM. Is there any way to export individual layers from EE?

Link to Code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0cf45e4f7b0976e1e8da7017b16e2a26

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the answer correctly, then you can just use the same `Export.image.toDrive` function to export single band images. You can do that do export separately `treeCover` or `treeLoss` images. I also recommend you use `region` to export only the region of interest.

```
Export.image.toDrive({
 image: treeCover, 
 description: 'TreeCover_Pasquia_Hills', 
 region: FB,
 scale: 1000,
 maxPixels: 1e9,
 crs: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```